# group stacked column highchart

Tags: highcharts

I would like to built a chart like the attached image below.
[image: HighChart stacked]

someone please help me how to achieve it. My data will be like this.

```
Date             Tenant  Jobs
2014-12-01        13    2827
2014-12-01        32    397
2014-12-01        82    85
2014-12-01        83    32
2014-12-01        86    939
```

I already tried the link [url]http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked[/url].  But not sure how to pass the values dynamically. The Dates and tenant will be dynamic.

Comment: How your source of data looks like?

Comment: and also, I have to ask - how can a chart like that possibly be useful? How can any use possibly determine what any of those values are with so many series, so many legend entries, and the distored 3D view? Might as well use a Jackson Pollack painting to display your data...

Comment: Thanks for your comments. This is a comparison chart, one can easily find out the best performer Tenant out of this. Sebastian I already gave the screen shot of my source data. Still here is the same.                         Date             Tenant  Jobs
2014-12-01        13    2827
2014-12-01        32    397
2014-12-01        82    85
2014-12-01        83    32
2014-12-01        86    939